# Отключение каскадного удаления в Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

В базе есть две сущности, скажем, Parent и Child:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

При этом EF создавая таблицы в базе указывает внешний ключ с параметром Delete rule = Cascade, а мне нужно отключить это поведение.

[image: Foreign key]

(Ещё странно, что для некоторых таблиц такое поведение уже отключено почему-то... почему -- неясно, не вижу никакой логики)

Как это можно сделать, желательно без использования Fluent API?

Answer (score 0):

Используя Data annotations этого не сделать, только через Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Children)
        .WithRequired(c => c.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

}
```

Также если нужно это сделать для всех таблиц в базе, то можно просто отключить конвенцию:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

По поводу того, что для некоторых таблиц ON DELETE CASCADE отключено.

По умолчанию, если свойство-внешний ключ зависимой сущности не представляет собой тип Nullable, то в таблице для этой сущности устанавливается каскадное удаление, по удалению главной сущности. Если тип Nullable - каскадное удаление не добавляется в таблицу.

Comment: Да, достаточно сделать `int? ParentID` и каскадное удаление не создаётся.