# Отключение каскадного удаления в Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Я хочу создать 2 таблицы: Team, Match, где в таблице Match существует 2 ссылки на таблицу Team. Когда пытаюсь сгенерировать БД, появляется ошибка связанная с каскадным удалением. Можете подсказать, как решить проблему?

```
public class Team {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class Match {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int? HomeId { get; set; }
  public int? GuestId { get; set; }

  public Team Home { get; set; }
  public Team Guest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Отключить через `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` в modelBinder. Теория тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.2.php

Comment: И я не очень разбираюсь в предметной области, но мне кажется, что для любого матча известны и домашняя и гостевая команда - поэтому я бы заменил int? на int.

Comment: @AK большое спасибо, сейчас проверю

Comment: Надо же, совсем из головы вылетело: когда-то [уже писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/657229/213987) себе памятку по этому вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вам нужно до конца расставить навигационные свойства:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Match> GuestMatches { get; set; }
}

public class Match
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HomeId { get; set; }
    public int GuestId { get; set; }
    public Team Home { get; set; }
    public Team Guest { get; set; }
}
```

Во-вторых, в ApplicationDbContext добавьте:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Match>()
           .HasOne(m => m.Home)
           .WithMany(t => t.HomeMatches)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.Entity<Match>()
           .HasOne(m => m.Guest)
           .WithMany(t => t.GuestMatches)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

(Формально хватило бы и один каскад отключить)

На метаинте есть подробности: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.2.php

Comment: Навигационные свойства расставлять до конца не обязательно :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Не учите детей плохому ;)

Comment: Иногда плохое - это как раз лишние циклы в графе объектов...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Любопытно. Пример какой-нибудь есть или ссылка где почитать?